# How to join table with multiple columns in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code in linq, what I am trying to do is joining tables with multiple columns of one table

```
//NOT A VALID CODE
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on ((t1.ID equals t2.orderId) || (t1.ID equals t2.pickupId ))// how can I do this
...
...
```

How can I achieve this in Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = from t1 in table1
            from t2 in table2
            where t1.ID == t2.orderId || t1.ID == t2.pickupId
            select new { t1, t2};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an anonymous type

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on new { t1.ID, t1.pickupId } equals new { t2.ID, t2.pickupId }
...
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. In my e.g. `table1` doesn't have `pickupId` that's why I got problem.